# OpenCV 3.0 which parameters in DepthCleaner function?

Tags: c++, kinect, opencv3.0, image-enhancement

I am working on enhancing Kinect's depth image using the DepthCleaner function of OpenCV 3.0. I am using the following codes to use this function.

```
char fileName[64];
Mat depth_image = Mat(480, 640, CV_16UC1);
Mat output = Mat(480, 640, CV_16U);

snprintf(fileName, sizeof(fileName), "Depth_Image/Img1.png");
depth_image = imread(fileName, -1);

DepthCleaner* depthc = new DepthCleaner(CV_16U, 3, DepthCleaner::DEPTH_CLEANER_NIL);

depthc->operator ()(depth_image,output);
```

My question is: the `operator()()` method of DepthCleaner needs points of the depth image as input. Could you please inform how do I get those points from the input depth image? I am using C++ in Eclipse IDE.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31335524/opencv-3-0-rgbd-depthcleaner is the question solved?

Comment: I used the source code of the function.